# Save DataFrame to csv encounters error "ImportError: cannot import name 'StringIO'"

Tags: python, pandas, stringio

I have a pandas DataFrame `output_df` that I can manipulate or print without problems. However, when I run `output_df.to_csv(output_filename)`, it gives an error:

```
  File "my_file.py", line 169, in run_attribute_generator
    output_df.to_csv(output_filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3204, in to_csv
    New Series or DataFrame with updated labels.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (StringIO, range, zip)
ImportError: cannot import name 'StringIO'
```

My pandas version is 0.25.1

Comment: Seems related to a bug https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/655.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it from [here](https://github.com/pandas-ml/pandas-ml/issues/124)

It seems that you have to downgrade your pandas version to 0.24.2 or lower.
Hope it helps